# Are there any open source projects in D?

Tags: open-source, d

I remember looking at D about 2 years ago, and it looked nice, was actually faster than C for some of the typical language benchmarks, and in general seemed ok, but I didn't find any real projects written in D back then, so I just left as a I came.

Now that a few years have passed I was wondering if there have been any projects done in D, hopefully open source to look at the code and see how its going, or is D dead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the projects in [DSource](http://www.dsource.org/projects/).

Give a look also to the [DLinks](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/dlinks.html) page.

Answer (score 3):

On SourceForge, if you apply the filter "Require", "Programming language", "D", you get 113 hits, so it would seem so.

I've always been a bit worried about developing in D since I know little about this Digital Mars mob. Does D have a future outside of just piquing the interest of some nerds (using that term in a non-disparaging way)?

Comment: Exactly my same concern. But then again I thought the same from C# :)

Comment: Well, MS is a slightly bigger beast than DigitalMars. But I'm still avoiding C# since Mono is not yet up to scratch and I need cross-platform capability.

Comment: Pax, you could look at the question, "Does the D programming language have a future?" for some answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you like games, check out [Kento Cho at ABA Games](http://www.asahi-net.or.jp/~cs8k-cyu/index_e.html) (anything under Windows). His Windows games are written in D and demonstrate D with [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/).

His code is very, very nice to read. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

look also at [code.google.com](http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label:d&btn=Search+Projects) for some more D projects.